# "They're a power man should never have trifled with", why not "never have been trifled with"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> Haratis: Your family has dragons
> Targaryen: They're a power man should never have trifled with

These lines come from the latest [HBO House of the Dragon Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DotnJ7tTA34) at around 1:45. In my understanding, the line should be: They're a power man should never have **been** trifled with. Why has this important *been* been omitted?

Comment: Because 'man should never have trifled with them'. 'Been' would make the sentence nonsense.

Comment: They're a power [that] man should never have trifled with. versus the passive: They should never have been trifled with by man.

Comment: Why do you think "been" should be there? Who do you think is trifling with who? Indeed, what do you think "trifled with" means?

Comment: I have thought it's They're a power man [that] should never have trifled with. I know i am wrong, why you guys just like keep blaming me for this question? English is my second language, i learn it every day and that's why i ask silly question like this, but that's how i make progress.

Comment: @Lambie thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence from the trailer is correct.

The implication is that man (i.e. human beings) trifled with dragons at some point and shouldn't have done this. (The previous line in the trailer is "Your family has dragons", making it clear that dragons, collectively, are the power that man should not have trifled with.)

"They're a power man should never have been trifled with," as you proposed, is grammatically incorrect. You can state that something "has been" trifled with, but this is a passive construction, meaning that the object of the verb "trifle" must be the grammatical subject of the sentence. For example: "This power should never have been trifled with." The sentence in the trailer, however, isn't a passive one.

Comment: I see, thanks for your clear explanation.